# Modify volume while streaming with PyAudio

Tags: python, wav, pyaudio

I am trying to stream a .WAV file whilst both stripping away one of the sound channels, so it only plays on one speaker, and whilst reducing the volume.

The reason I am using PyAudio is that I will have to be able to

- Stream multiple files at once
- Play sound out of specific speakers (left/right)
- Interrupt the playing of sound files

and was unable to find any other python libraries which allowed those features.

I have the following code, modified from PyAudio's streaming example. It plays a WAV file from one speaker, but I was unable to find a way to modify the volume in any way.

```
"""PyAudio Example: Play a wave file."""

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys 

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream (2)
sampwidth = wf.getsampwidth()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(sampwidth),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

# read data
data = bytearray(wf.readframes(CHUNK))

# play stream (3)
while len(data) > 0:
    #remove left channel
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        if i % (sampwidth*2) < sampwidth:
            data[i] = 0

    #reduce volume by 50%
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        # use magic???
        pass

    stream.write(bytes(data))
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
    if len(data) > 0:
        data = bytearray(data)

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

If anyone can give me any pointers, I would appreciate it. I feel like the answer will require a better understanding of how the WAV files are formatted than I currently possess. I tried `data[i] = int(data[i]/2)` and other similar simple arithmetic, but the output was simply distorted, which shows me that the WAV file format is not as simple as I believed.

Comment: Your simple arithmetic doesn't work because `data` is a `bytearray` and those operations are not defined (and they don't really make sense, because it's just bytes, not numbers). Are you willing to use NumPy? Using NumPy arrays would make those kind of operations possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub). It uses pyaudio and has a simple method to change volume.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subprocess` module:

From `subprocess` import call

```
 call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "0%"])
```

To increase The volume by 10%:

```
call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "10%+"])
```

To decrease The volume by 10%:

```
call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "10%-"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` for this without calling subprocess. Code exaple:

```
import numpy

def audio_datalist_set_volume(datalist, volume):
    """ Change value of list of audio chunks """
    sound_level = (volume / 100.)

    for i in range(len(datalist)):
        chunk = numpy.fromstring(datalist[i], numpy.int16)

        chunk = chunk * sound_level

        datalist[i] = chunk.astype(numpy.int16)
```

Note: `datalist` is your sound array

To use it, just pass your sound data to the function and set volume level.

Comment: The company I worked for 3 years ago when I asked this has long ceased development, but I appreciate the suggestion nonetheless