# I'm trying to increase volume (amplitude) of raw streaming in Python

Tags: python, audio, streaming, volume

I'm trying to increase audio volume (amplitude) of a received stream. Everything worked before I tried to increase the volume, but after the increase (multiplied all array elements by a value, in this case, 3), I can hear noise together with voice. How can I solve it?

A note: the emitter side is a ESP32 with wifi, with I2S microphone. Please see my python code:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pyaudio

UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 3333
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt32, channels=1, rate=44100, output=True)

while True:
    data1, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)       
    signal = np.fromstring(data1, dtype=np.uint8)
    signal=np.multiply(signal, 3) 
    stream.write(signal)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664121/modify-volume-while-streaming-with-pyaudio

Comment: I saw this post, and does not help me