# How can I change the volume of a stream playing in pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have a normal stream in Pyaudio that plays a wav file but I can not find any way to change the volume of the stream. I tried multiplying the data by some number but that did not work.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
chunk = 1024
af = wave.open("filename.wav", 'rb')
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = pa.open(format = 
pa.get_format_from_width(af.getsampwidth()),
            channels = af.getnchannels(),
            rate = af.getframerate(),
            output_device_index=9,
            output = True)

rd_data = af.readframes(chunk)

while rd_data != '':
    #do some majic to change the volume
    stream.write(rd_data)
    rd_data = af.readframes(chunk)
```

Comment: [Is this a duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36664121/2449857)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify volume while streaming with PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664121/modify-volume-while-streaming-with-pyaudio)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` for this:

```
import numpy

def audio_datalist_set_volume(datalist, volume):
    """ Change value of list of audio chunks """
    sound_level = (volume / 100.)

    for i in range(len(datalist)):
        chunk = numpy.fromstring(datalist[i], numpy.int16)

        chunk = chunk * sound_level

        datalist[i] = chunk.astype(numpy.int16)
```